# How to show via inductive proof (and without the use of the binomial theorem) that $ {n\choose k} \in \mathbb{N} $?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

How do I show via inductive proof (and without the use of the binomial theorem) that
$$ {n\choose k} \in {\mathbb{N}} $$ $$\text{ for  all }\: n,k \in \mathbb{N}_0\: \text{ with }\: n≥k .$$

For my induction proof, I would show that$$ 
{n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k} = {n+1 \choose k}  
$$
is true.
However, how do I start the induction correctly with the base cases and the hypothesis? As far as I know, I cannot simply assume $$ {n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k}, $$  so how do I come to this derivation?

**Remark** I was able to find an answer (posted below).

Comment: Use the definition  of $\binom nk$: it is the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$.

Comment: I interpret the "use induction" constraint differently.  Without induction, just using direct algebraic manipulation, you have that $$ 
{n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k} = {n+1 \choose k}.  
$$  Then, once this is established, induction indicates that each row of Pascal's triangle corresponds to the elements (in order) $\binom{n}{0}, \binom{n}{1}, \cdots, \binom{n}{n}$.  This is because Pascal's triangle follows the rule that each number is the sum of the two numbers above it.  Once this is established, you are done, because every element in Pascal's triangle is an integer.

Comment: @Bernard There are other definitions. For instance, $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ isn't as obviously integral.

Comment: @Bernhard what would be already knowledge from the binomial theorem, which is not allowed to use. I must use induction to proof it

Comment: @user2661923 proof by induction is required. I can't simply skip it

Comment: There are other definitions,  but if it's called a binomial coefficient, there's a reason. What you mention is not a definition – it is a proved formula.

Comment: Depends on what the requirement is.  If the requirement is to prove, by induction that $\binom{n}{k}$ is an integer, then my approach, which does use induction, is good.  If instead, you are required to use induction to prove the preliminary result that $\binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k},$ **then**, your criticism of my approach is appropriate.

Comment: @Bernard High school textbook authors can define it whichever way they see fit, and personally I usually don't see them used for binomials first, so that definition wouldn't make sense in a teaching setting. You could just acknowledge that it is possible to teach things in a different order rather than claiming there is only one correct way.

Comment: I didn''t say  there's only one correct way – there's also a combinatorial definition, but using a definition based on factorials, heuristically, is meaningless.

Comment: @Bernard, you can prove it by induction for $ \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k} $ . The only question i had was basically how i can make this assumption. I finally found my answer: $ \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom {n-1}{r} $ If you want to display $ \binom{n+1}{k} $ you have to add + 1 to the right side, which will give you $ \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n+1}{k} $. Than, one can easily show with  $ \binom{n}{k-1} + \binom{n}{k} $ with the faculty math rules that it is indeed equal to $  \binom{n+1}{k} $ and therefor it's true for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $

Comment: What's you definition of the binomial coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

${n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k}={n+1\choose k}$ follows from the definition of ${n\choose k}$.

${0\choose 0}=1$ by definition.

*Base Case:* ${1\choose 0}={1\choose 1}=1.$

*Induction Hypothesis:* Suppose that ${n\choose k}$ is a natural number $\text{ for  all }\: k \in \mathbb{N}_0\: \text{ with }\: k\leq n$.

*Inductive Step:* Consider the case ${n+1\choose k}$. $${n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k}={n+1\choose k};$$ Using the Induction Hypothesis it follows that ${n+1\choose k}$ is a natural number $\text{ for  all }\: k \in \mathbb{N}\: \text{ with }\: k\leq n$. By definition ${n+1\choose 0}={n+1\choose n+1}=1$. Thus, ${n\choose k}$ is always a natural number.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who looks for an answer, i was able to find the solution due to the help of some comments and even more research.

$$ {n+1 \choose k} = {n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k}$$

is obviously the induction hypothesis someone wants to use for an induction proof. The problem i had was to figure out how we can make that assumption.

So by definition:

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1} + \binom {n-1}{k}$$

Now, if we add change that left side to $ \binom {n+1}{k} $ we have to add the + 1 also to the right side of n. So on right side, we have two (n-1), they will become simply n, as we add your + 1 to it. The k doesn't change, so we get finally:

$$ {n+1 \choose k} = {n\choose k-1}+{n\choose k} $$

Now, from this point, you can simply use the faculty rule and use the standard mathematical rules to show that it is indeed equal to $ {n+1 \choose k} $